# Converter DataTable em List Entity

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Estou tentando usar o código abaixo para converter mas ele dá erro em todo lugar que tem o `T` e `where`. O que poderia ser?

```
// function that set the given object from the given data row
public static void SetItemFromRow(T item, DataRow row)
    where T : new()
{
    // go through each column
    foreach (DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns)
    {
        // find the property for the column
        PropertyInfo p = item.GetType().GetProperty(c.ColumnName);

        // if exists, set the value
        if (p != null && row[c] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            p.SetValue(item, row[c], null);
        }
    }
}

// function that creates an object from the given data row
public static T CreateItemFromRow(DataRow row)
    where T : new()
{
    // create a new object
    T item = new T();

    // set the item
    SetItemFromRow(item, row);

    // return 
    return item;
}

// function that creates a list of an object from the given data table
public static List CreateListFromTable(DataTable tbl)
    where T : new()
{
    // define return list
    List lst = new List();

    // go through each row
    foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
    {
        // add to the list
        lst.Add(CreateItemFromRow(r));
    }

    // return the list
    return lst;
}
```

[image: Veja o erro]

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas T é o que? O compilador não sabe o que é T, acho que é por isso que dá o erro. Diferente de uma lista genérica com o tipo genérico T. Caso eu esteja errado me corrijam por favor.

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe está errada. A declaração de uso de genérico é da seguinte forma:

```
public static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row)
    where T : class, new()
{

...

public static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row)
    where T : class, new()
{
```

`new()` indica para o código que a classe em questão tem um construtor nulo, então pode ser instanciada dentro do método.

Não precisa ser exatamente `class` a definição. Pode ser uma classe ou uma interface (o compilador vai entender que `T` é uma classe que implementa aquela interface).

Comment: Falta `<T>` na assinatura dos métodos para indicar que eles são genéricos: `public static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row)`. Também não é necessária a restrição `class`, a não ser que queiramos restringir `T` apenas a *reference types*, o que penso não ser o caso aqui.

Comment: @ramaral Corrigido conforme sua orientação. Obrigado. Sobre *reference types*, não creio que, pelo que o autor da pergunta colocou, o uso dos métodos será muito abrangente. Creio que `class` já resolva bem a questão.